# How to set android TabHost default view to be the second(or third) tab instead of the first tab to be the default view?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

How to change the default TabHost view to show the FrameLayout corresponding to the second or third tab to be the default view, as opposed to always being the first tab's corresponding Framelayout to be the default view? I want to do this as I do not change the ordering of the tab but only wanting to show default to be other than the first tab?

Answer (score -1):

use this line in you code by default it set "0".-
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(**1**);